# Magento + shopping cart price rule

Tags: php, magento

I am working on magento 1.9. I want to give my customers discount of $5 on purchasing on 3 products of same category, $10 on purchasing of 6 products, $15 on purchasing of 9 and so on and I achieve that but there is a small problem that it give discount only on exact quantity of product.

Example:

$5 discount is given on 3 quantity which is fine but if there are 4 products I want to give $5 discount.
and if there are 7 products then the discount of $10 as per 6 product is given.

Here is my rule

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to create "Tier Price" for your product. This will work for you.like this:
[image]

Comment: what is I have 3 different products of same category? is this work?